# Editor with dynamically allocated matrix in template

Tags: c++, templates, matrix, dynamic

I've got two classes (structs) - Editor and Matrix. The matrix itself is working fine. But if I want to use Matrix via Editor, it's not working. I believe there is some problem with memory because I can't deallocate and even use matrix inside the Editor struct. I've tried to allocate the matrix dynamically, but then I couldn't use the addRow method.

**Not really good with c++, but have to use those classes, can't use std::vector and stuff like that.**

Editor definition:

```
struct Editor
{
private:
    Matrix<std::string> data;
public:
    Editor();
    Editor(Matrix<std::string> oldData);
    ~Editor();
    void addRow(std::string* row);
    int getNumberOfRows();
    int getNumberOfColumns();
};
```

Editor implementation:

```
using namespace std;
Editor::Editor()
{
}

Editor::Editor(Matrix<string> oldData)
{
    data = oldData;
}
Editor::~Editor()
{
}
void Editor::addRow(std::string* row)
{
    data.addRow(row);
}
int Editor::getNumberOfRows()
{
    return this->data.getNumberOfRows();
}

int Editor::getNumberOfColumns()
{
    return this->data.getNumberOfColumns();
}
```

Matrix definition:

```
template<typename T>
struct Matrix
{
private:
    T** data;
    int numberOfRows;
    int numberOfColumns;
public:
    Matrix(int numberOfRows, int numberOfColumns);
    Matrix(const Matrix<T>& m);
    ~Matrix();
    int getNumberOfRows();
    int getNumberOfColumns();
    T getItem(int indexRow, int indexColumn) const;
    void addRow(T* newRow);
    T** getData();
};
```

Matrix implementation:

```
template<typename T>
inline Matrix<T>::Matrix(int numberOfRows, int numberOfColumns)
{
    this->numberOfColumns = numberOfColumns;
    this->numberOfRows = numberOfRows;
    this->data = new T * [numberOfRows];
    for (int i = 0; i < this->numberOfRows; i++)
    {
        this->data[i] = new T[numberOfColumns];
    }
}

template<typename T>
inline Matrix<T>::Matrix(const Matrix<T>& m)
{
    numberOfRows = m.numberOfRows;
    numberOfColumns = m.numberOfColumns;
    if (m.data)
    {
        data = new T * [numberOfRows];

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++)
            data[i] = new T[numberOfColumns];

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < numberOfColumns; j++)
            {
                data[i][j] = m.data[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
}

template<typename T>
inline Matrix<T>::~Matrix()
{
    
    for (int i = 0; i < this->numberOfRows; i++)
    {
        delete[] data[i];
    }
    
    delete[] data;
}

template<typename T>
inline int Matrix<T>::getNumberOfRows()
{
    return this->numberOfRows;
}

template<typename T>
inline int Matrix<T>::getNumberOfColumns()
{
    return this->numberOfColumns;
}

template<typename T>
inline T** Matrix<T>::getData()
{
    return this->data;
}

template<typename T>
inline T Matrix<T>::getItem(int indexRow, int indexColumn) const
{
    if (indexRow < 0 || indexRow > numberOfRows || indexColumn < 0 || indexColumn > numberOfColumns)
    {
        throw std::exception("not valid at least one of those indexes");
    }
    return this->data[indexRow][indexColumn];
}

template<typename T>
inline void Matrix<T>::addRow(T* newRow)
{
    if (newRow == nullptr)
    {
        throw std::exception("not valid row");
    }

    T** newData = new T * [numberOfRows + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows + 1; i++)
    {
        newData[i] = new T[numberOfColumns];
        for (int j = 0; j < numberOfColumns; j++)
        {
            if (i != this->numberOfRows)
            {
                newData[i][j] = data[i][j];
            }
            else {
                newData[i][j] = newRow[j];
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < this->numberOfRows; i++)
    {
        delete[] this->data[i];
    }
    delete[] this->data;

    this->data = newData;
    this->numberOfRows++;
}
```

Main:

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
    Matrix<string> mt{1,1};
    string* st = new string[3];
    st[0] = "aa";
    st[1] = "bb";
    st[2] = "cc";
    mt.addRow(st); // works
    Editor ed{ mt };
    ed.addRow(st); // doesn't work
    return 0;
}
```

It crashes in xstring* on this:

```
    _CONSTEXPR20_CONTAINER void _Copy_assign(const basic_string& _Right, false_type) {
        _Pocca(_Getal(), _Right._Getal());
        assign(_Right._Mypair._Myval2._Myptr(), _Right._Mypair._Myval2._Mysize);
    }
```

with code:

```
Exception: Read access violation.
_Right – 0xDDDDDDDD.
```

**EDIT:**
Did cut most of the stuff from the project to just show the minimum. Anyway, the answer with semi-shallow copy was the right. Altho I thought

```
struct = struct;
```

calls for copy constructor. But it seems that it doesn't. I had to add operator= to somehow make it work properly.

Comment: I'm surprised it even compiles: You declare one constructor as `Editor(Matrix<std::string> oldData);` but define it as `Editor::Editor(Matrix<string> oldData, string* columnNames)`. Also, `throw std::exception("not valid at least one of those indexes");` - `std::exception` doesn't have such a constructor.

Comment: *"can't use `std::vector`"*. So rewrite your own version. It would be simpler than `Matrix` with only one dimension

Comment: Maybe your `Matrix` does not implement rule of five correctly. Thus `Editor ed{ mt };` will make a semi-shallow copy, breaking something. That's just a guess, try to debug the code to see who deleted `_Right`.

Comment: Also, `Matrix` doesn't have a default constructor, but you try using that.